# onbeforeunload not working in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, onbeforeunload

I have very simple code just to show a warning before page refreshed. The code uses Codeigniter as a framework (not sure if Codeigniter is related to the issue). I have a view file (test_v.php) with the following code:

```
<?php ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body >
<p>Test onbeforeunload</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  return 'Do you really want to perform the action?';
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then I load this view file in a controller test.php
$this->load->view('test_v');

When I refresh the page, I expect to see a warning dialogue with the text 'Do you really want to perform the action?', but no warnings are shown at all.  I have tested with IE, Firefox, Chrome. None works.
I have also tried adding the js code to the body label like this:

```
<body onbeforeunload=" return 'Do you really want to perform the action?'">
```

not working either.
Could anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code you have should work fine. Can you verify you get the popup when you click either of the links in this slightly modified version, https://jsfiddle.net/043vymod/

Comment: @CBroe, Yes, I get popups when clicking either of the links. So it's very likely that this issue is related to Codeigniter framework.

Comment: But CI is on the server side, that should have little influence on how the client behaves when it comes to client-side coding.

Comment: @CBroe, I just realized that the popups I get when I click the links shows a very different message. On Chrome and IE it shows "Changes you made may not be saved." but on Firefox it shows "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave — information you’ve entered may not be saved.". None of the browsers shows "Do you really want to perform the action?",  which is what is expected to show, right?

Comment: Not all browsers will show a custom message, no. I’m guessing custom messages in this situation might have some kind of abuse/scam potential.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using as an event listener like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault(); // If you prevent default behavior in Mozilla Firefox prompt will always be shown
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Per [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

> Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with. Moreover, some don't display them at all.

Might be the cause of your problem. I tested on a page and I didn't get the alert until interacted with the page.

Comment: Thank you Mike, but your code does not work either, in fact I have tried it before. I don't think it's because the browser blocked the alert, because I tried doing something else (such as using window.location to redirect to another website) in the function and still it didn't work. I guess the function wasn't executed at all.

Comment: If you use this exact code it should work. You should test with just a plain HTML file and go from there.

Comment: I tested with .php file, as is used in Codeigniter. Do you mean I have to use .html file?

Comment: See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oyn8fbgu/). You should get the prompt when you try to leave the page or reload.

Comment: Yes. I can get the prompt when leaving or reloading the page. So it's not a problem of the browser. I guess it's related to Codeigniter, the MVC structure.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for this.  I was registering a function called "beforeUnloadHandler" associated with the beforeunload event:

```html
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", beforeUnloadHandler);
```

In order to get rid of that message I had to call this JavaScript in order to remove the event handler just before the user navigated away.  It turned out the second parameter is required.

see: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_removeeventlistener.asp

```html
window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", beforeUnloadHandler);
```